# log4net, configure ColoredConsoleAppender to not show exception

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, appender

How can I make the ColoredConsoleAppender only show the message?

Despite leaving out `%exception` from conversionPattern both the exception-message and stacktrace is shown. If it cannot be done by [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410059/logging-innerexception-using-log4net/2410108#2410108) is there some method to override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I now know that it is possible and how to do it:

[Log4Net - Logging out the Exception stacktrace only for certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659271/log4net-logging-out-the-exception-stacktrace-only-for-certain-files/3660529#3660529)